# How to apply LIMIT on a queryset in serializer field?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a question regarding LIMIT on query-set for a field.

I have a following serializer:

```py
class UserProfileSrializer(serializers.Serializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
        serializers.Serializer.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


    boats = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, source="boatmodel_set", slug_field="boat_name",
                                         read_only=True)
    articles = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, source="article_set", read_only=True)
    comment = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, source="get_comments", read_only=True)
```

where each field represent different mode instance.

Parent model – USER
Secondary model 1 – BoatModel, traversed as "boatmodel_set" against USER model
Secondary model2 – Article , traversed as "article_set" against USER model

Views

```py
class UserProfileView(views.APIView):   

    def get(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        serializer = serializers.UserProfileSrializer(user)
        data = serializer.data
        #data["boats"] = sorted(data["boats"])[:10]  - need something better as it overloads DB
        #data["articles"] = data["articles"][:10]
        return Response(data)
```

Question is if I dont want to serialize and render all entries from "boatmodel_set" and "article_set" that have relations with the user ( might be hundreds), but instead I want to limit them as [ : 10] entries of "boatmodel_set"  and [ : 10] entries of "article_set" only and still keeping these fields read_only and possible without callable source() and methodfield. Is it possible to override it somewhere?

Thanks

P.S. comment field -please exclude from scope -different topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the serializer field get method and limit these by yourself. Here is how you do it:

```py
class UserProfileSrializer(serializers.Serializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
        serializers.Serializer.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


    boats = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, source="boatmodel_set", slug_field="boat_name",
                                         read_only=True)
    articles = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, source="article_set", read_only=True)
    comment = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, source="get_comments", read_only=True)


    def get_boats(self, obj):
        # access the boats like this
        boats = obj.boats
        boats_limited = ... # limit your boats here
        return boats_limited


    def get_articles(self, obj):
        # access the articles like this
        articles = obj.articles
        articles_limited = ... # limit your articles here
        return articles_limited
```